# Image appears in one template, but not in the other

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to create an app with 2 pages, a general one an a view details page.
In both pages I need the image of the product. In the general view, the image appears, but not in the details page.
This is my html for details page:

```
<div class="span4">
    <h2>{{ prod.name }}</h2><br>
    <img alt="" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{prod.image}}"></a>                                               
</div>
```

And here is the html for the general page (the same image is defined here as {{ values.3.0 }}):

```
{% for key, values in prodmatrix.items %}
  <li class="span3">
  <div class="product-box">
  <span class="sale_tag"></span>
  <p><a href="{% url "home" %}{{ values.3.0 }}"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{values.1.0}}" alt="" /></a></p>
  <a href="product_detail.html" class="title">{{ values.0.0 }}</a><br/>
  <a href="products.html" class="category">Commodo consequat</a>
  <p class="price">#{{values.2.0}} #{{values.2.1}} #{{values.2.2}}</p>
  </div></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Both templates are based on a base, which already imports:

```
 {% load static %}
  {% load i18n %}
    {% load staticfiles %}
```

Here is the view for the detailed template:

```
def single_product(request, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug)
    prod = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
    reviews = Review.objects.get(product=prod.id)
    reviewmatrix = {}
    i = 0
    try:
        for rev in reviews:
            reviewmatrix[str(i)] = [[review.review_text]]
            u = User.objects.get(username=rev.user)
            i = i + 1
    except:
        u = User.objects.get(username=reviews.user)
        reviewmatrix[str(i)] = [[reviews.review_text]]

    return render_to_response('product_detail.html', {'prod':prod, 'reviews':reviews, 'user':u.first_name})
```

And here is the view for the general template

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user
        prods = Product.objects.all()
        i = 0
        prodmatrix = {}
        for prod in prods:
            #                       0             1           2    3
            prodmatrix[str(i)] = [[prod.name], [prod.image], [], [prod.slug]] 
            review = Review.objects.get(product=prod.id) #   ^ this is for tags 
            for tags in review.tag.all():     #                           
                print tags.name
                prodmatrix[str(i)][2].append(tags.name) # append only tags 
            i = i + 1
        #for prod in prods:
        #    tags = Review.objects.filter(product=prod.id)
        #    for tag in tags:
        #        prodmatrix[str(i)] = [[prod.name], [prod.image], [tag]]
        #    i = i + 1    
        return render(request, 'home.html',{'prodmatrix':prodmatrix, 'prods':prods})
    else:
        products = Product.objects.all()

        return render(request, 'home.html',{'products':products})
        return render(request, 'home.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second view is using the `render` shortcut, so the context processors are run, which includes the `STATIC_URL` variable in the context. The first view uses the old `render_to_response` shortcut, which by default does not run context processors. Change it to use `render`.